# Why the visibility hidden must add position absolute in css?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
 ul {list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0;   }
  li{ float:left;  background-color:#444444; text-align: center; width: 100px;  
  border-right:1px solid white; color: white; }

li ul li { float: none;
         border-top:1px solid white;}

         li ul { visibility:hidden; position: absolute;}
        li:hover ul {visibility:visible;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
     <ul>
       <li>home</li>
       <li id="up">pages
       <ul class="down">
       <li>a</li>
       <li>b</li>
       <li>c</li>                  
      </ul>
       </li> 
     </ul>    
</body>
</html>
```

In the li ul section if i only put  visibility:hidden, it does not hide up there is still a column there, why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is to do with the difference between `visibility: hidden;` and say `display: none;`

`visibility: hidden;` hides the element, but it still takes up space in the layout.

`display: none;` removes the element completely from the document. It does not take up any space, even though the HTML for it is still in the source code.

`position: absolute;` The element is removed from the normal flow entirely.

Comment: so, what the function of position absolute in the css?

Comment: The `position: absolute;` is removing your element from the flow and combined with `visibility: hidden;` is causing similar behavior as `display: none;`

Comment: but why if i replace visibility: hidden with display: nen, when i hover it does not show any thing.

Comment: Because in your hover you are still setting `visibility` you need to set `display: block;`. Otherwise you are setting `visibility: visible;` which it technically already is because you aren't setting `visibility: hidden;`

Comment: Think of it as `visibility: visible;` shown, `visibility: hidden;` is hidden. `display: none;` has no display, `display: block;` is shown as a normal block element.